Validation ::marker missing in form error view
Im very new to CodeIgniter, using 4.5.5. I got a HTML form, a sophisticated one, to manage data in a database. Suddenly the validation form error view does not show errors with a point marker in different rows, but all errors without markers in a single row. I dont know what i have changed causing this. I didn engage a git, so i cannot roll back. When i look into the HTML code, CodeIgniter produces, the only difference to the tutorial first app i see is the ::marker is missing in the li tags.
See the form error view
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\FlightsModel;
use CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException;

class Airports extends BaseController
{
    public function new(?array $form_data = null)
    {
        helper('form');

    if( is_null($form_data)) {
        $form_data['rwystored'] = false;
        $form_data['ICAOcode']  = "";
        $form_data['runways' ]  = null; // indexed array
        $form_data['radios'  ]  = []; // indexed array for radio number with associative array for sign, freq and type
    }
    $this->session->set($form_data);

        return view('templates/header', ['title' => 'Create an airport'])
            . view('airports/create', $form_data)
            . view('templates/footer');
    }
    
    public function create()
    {
        helper('form');

    $form_data = $this->session->get();
        $data = $this->request->getPost(['ICAOcode', 'newrunway']);

        // Checks whether the submitted data passed the validation rules.
        if (! $this->validateData($data, [
            'ICAOcode' => 'required|max_length[4]|min_length[4]',
            'newrunway' => 'max_length[3]',
        ])) {
            // The validation fails, so returns the form.
        $form_data['rwystored'] = false;
            return $this->new($form_data);
        }

        $post = $this->validator->getValidated();

    // Store new runway and redisplay the form
        $data = $this->request->getPost(['action']);
    if($data['action'] === 'runway') {
        $rwy = $post['newrunway'];
        if($rwy !== "") {
            $form_data['runways'][] = $rwy;
        $form_data['rwystored'] = true;
        }
            return $this->new($form_data);
    }

        return view('templates/header', ['title' => 'Create an airport'])
            . view('airports/success')
            . view('templates/footer');
    }
}


airports/create.php :
<h2><?= esc($title) ?></h2>

<?= session()->getFlashdata('error') ?>
<?= validation_list_errors() ?>

<form action="/airports" method="post">
    <?= csrf_field() ?>
    
         <label for="ICAOcode">ICAOcode</label>
         <input type="input" name="ICAOcode" value="<?= set_value('ICAOcode') ?>">
         <br>

    <fieldset>
         <legend>Runways</legend>

     <?php if(!is_null($runways)): ?>

         <ul>
         <?php foreach ($runways as $runway): ?>

             <li><a href="/airports/new/<?= esc($runway, 'url') ?>"><?= esc($runway) ?></a></li>

         <?php endforeach ?>
         </ul>

     <?php endif ?>
 
         <label for="newrunway">New RWY</label>
     <input type="input" name="newrunway" value="<?php if(!$rwystored) echo(set_value('newrunway')) ?>">
     
     <button type="submit" name="action" value="runway">Enter</button>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
         <legend>Radios</legend>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#MKK">MKK</a></li>
       <li>171.00</li>
       <li>&nbsp;VORDME Ha</li>
     </ul>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#AK">AK</a></li>
       <li>341.0</li>
       <li>&nbsp;NDB HH</li>
     </ul>
     <label for="newsign">New sign</label>
         <input type="input" name="newsign" value="<?= set_value('newsign') ?>">

     <label for="newfreq">Freq</label>
         <input type="input" name="newfreq" value="<?= set_value('newfreq') ?>">
     
     <label for="newtype">Type</label>
         <input type="input" name="newtype" value="<?= set_value('newtype') ?>">
     
         <input type="submit" name="radio" value="Enter">
    </fieldset>

         <input type="submit" name="saveindb" value="Save in DB">
         <input type="submit" name="abort" value="Abort">
         <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
</form>



It looks like your not return back to the form or any view with validation errors you can use method $this->validate($array_of_rules) and return back validation error if found
for example
public function new(){
  $rule = [
        'ICAOcode' => 'required|max_length[4]|min_length[4]',
        'newrunway' => 'max_length[3]',
    ];
  if($this->validate($rule)){
    //do some stuff validation passed
  }else{
    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
  }
}

make sure in your veiw you have called helper('form') and then in your views output validation errors by <?= validation_list_errors() ?>
